# Name to large to display on ion-select option once you selected the value

Tags: html, css, angular, select, ionic-framework

I would like to display the large name on the area when I select an option from my select.

Actually, the name selected is : 'Speciall Academy Pizza' But on the screen is just displayed 'Special Academy...'.

On the next image you can see the problem:

[image]

And here the code from these selects:

```
   <ion-item *ngIf="itemLevelSelected !== ''">
  <ion-label>
    level 1:
  </ion-label>
  <ion-select  interface="popover" [(ngModel)]="categorySelected" (ngModelChange)="setCategorySelected(categorySelected)">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let x of information">{{x.name}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
<ion-item *ngIf="categorySelected">
  <ion-label>
    level 2:
  </ion-label>
  <ion-select   interface="popover"  [(ngModel)]="subCategorySelected" (ngModelChange)="setSubCategorySelected(subCategorySelected)" >
    <ion-option *ngFor="let x of subCategory"  text-wrap>{{x.name}}</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

How could I display the full content of the large name?

Thanks.

Comment: Use chrome dev tools to check that there is no excessive padding or margin.

Comment: I've already cheked.. The problem is the size of divs are fixed, and there is a maximum padding, the one just let you increase the size like if you were did nothing. Thanks to answer anyway.